# PHP object serialization for several large objects

Tags: php, performance, session, serialization, large-data

I am developiong a php application which builds several large collections of objects in the course of interacting with the user.  The objects need to persist across requests from the user and I've used php sessions to successfully implement this.  The objects are persisted until the user is satisfied with what they have done and they request the information represented by the objects to be saved.

In profiling the application I found that the session start takes about half of the total time of a request (about 4 seconds in total for a request).  Since not all stored objects are used on each request from the user, I attempted to improve the responsiveness of the application by selectively restoring the objects needed for the request.  To do this I have serialized the objects to individual files and only unserialized those required.  This change actually blew up the application because the serialize/unserialize consumed huge amounts of memory (and time to run).  It surprised me that the session handler could serialize and unserialize all of the objects in less time and lower memory consumption than my attempt to do only a subset.  I believe this may be due to the loading of all the serialized object data into memory, but I'm not sure.

Following is the code to serialize and unserialize the objects that I have used:

Code to write the serialized object to files:

```
public static function writeClose() {
    foreach (self::$activeRegistries as $registryName=>$registry) {
        if (isset($_SESSION["filemap"]) && isset($_SESSION["filemap"]["registries"]) && isset($_SESSION["filemap"]["registries"][$registryName])) {
            $path = $_SESSION["filemap"]["registries"][$registryName];
            if (file_put_contents($path, serialize($registry)) === false) {
                throw new repositoryException("Exception while writing the '$registryName' registry to storage");
            }
        } else {
            throw new repositoryException("Could not find the file path for the '$registryName' registry");
        }
    }
}
```

Code to retrieve the serialized objects:

```
private static function getRegistry($registryName) {
    // First check to see if the registry is already active in this request
    if (isset(self::$activeRegistries[$registryName])) {
        $registry = self::$activeRegistries[$registryName];
    } else {
        // The registry is not active, so see if it is stored for the session
        if (isset($_SESSION["filemap"]) && isset($_SESSION["filemap"]) && isset($_SESSION["filemap"]["registries"][$registryName])) {
            $filePath = $_SESSION["filemap"]["registries"][$registryName];
            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                $registry = unserialize(file_get_contents($filePath));
                self::$activeRegistries[$registryName] = $registry;
            } else {
                throw new repositoryException("Exception while getting serialized object for registry '$registryName'");
            }
        } else {
            // The registry is not saved in the session, so create a new one
            $registry = self::createRegistry($registryName);
            $filePath = "/tmp/" . session_id() . $registryName;
            $_SESSION["filemap"]["registries"][$registryName] = $filePath;
            self::$activeRegistries[$registryName] = $registry;
        }
    }
    return $registry;
}
```

How can the application be improved over using the php session handler to retrieve all of the collections for each request?

Comment: So you have used files to store data for user instead of session right? and you want to have data for a user over requests. and I think putting it in a temp file would be a good solution but you should make it uniq. but for more help I should know more about the codes and **maybe** AJAX can help you too.

Comment: I have used the php session handler and files containing serialized representations of the user created objects.  The serialization and unserialization process conxumes huge amounts of memory and time.  The sessions work properly and are much more efficient in terms of memory and time, but still consume about half or the total time needed to handle a request from the user.  I am looking for a way to improve the performance. The code I used to perform the serialization and unserialization is given in my original post If you meed to see more code, please be specific on what else you need to see.

Comment: I didn't say I need to see any code. I said I need to know more about codes. About the process. I need to know about things like how much data need to be stored or restored in each request? Is there some requests that would need none of that data or some of that data? Perhaps there are ways to improve performance if we need to set or get small parts of data in each request. at least give me a simulated code simulated data and simulated requests to help me help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to speed up your existing session based implementation by changing where your session is stored.  By default, session data is written to a file on the server, and then correlated via a browser cookie.  If your session contains large amounts of data, the time you are seeing is likely seek time and read time for the physical drive.

However, PHP supports several methods of session storage.  I would suggest trying the MemCached option:  http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "localhost:11211"
```

You will of course need to install MemCached.